# passing QueryString value to selected item in drop down box

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I am trying to pass project ID from  Query String to ddb_projectList  to make the item selected and populate GridView but my problem is when the page load it select the first append Item. Note the selected value still -1

can anyone help  to fix the problem

---

code:

```
 public partial class TasksInProjects : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get loged in user id UserID from MembershipUser 
            MembershipUser memberUser = Membership.GetUser();
            string StrUserID = memberUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
            Guid userID = Guid.Parse(StrUserID);
            hf_userID.Value = userID.ToString();

            if (Request.QueryString["projectID"] == null)
            {


                //ddl_projects.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["projectID"];

                if (ddl_projects.SelectedValue != "-1")
                {

                    Guid projectID = Guid.Parse(ddl_projects.SelectedValue);
                    gv_TaskListForUser.DataSource = Task.GetTasksInProjectForUser(userID, projectID);
                    gv_TaskListForUser.DataBind();
                }

            }
            else
            {

                //ddl_projects.Visible = false;
                //Guid projectID = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["projectID"]);
                //gv_TaskListForUser.DataSource = Task.GetTasksInProjectForUser(userID, projectID);
                //gv_TaskListForUser.DataBind();

                ddl_projects.SelectedItem.Value = Request.QueryString["projectID"];
                Guid projectID = Guid.Parse(ddl_projects.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
                gv_TaskListForUser.DataSource = Task.GetTasksInProjectForUser(userID, projectID);
                gv_TaskListForUser.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
ddl_projects.ClearSelection();
ddl_projects.Items.FindByValue(Request.QueryString["projectID"]).Selected = true;
```

**On a side note**

I would recommend wrapping this up to prevent errors from occurring. Users often decide to play around with the URL. So it's best that you do as much checking as possible in case they do decide to fiddle! Just an example because validation all depends on the scope of what you're trying to achieve, but if I were you I would use at least the following:

```
int projectID = 0;

// Check the query string is an integer
if (int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["projectID"], out projectID))
{
    // You could apply addition checks here, such as check that the project id is valid etc.
    ListItem projectItem = ddl_projects.Items.FindByValue(projectID.ToString());

    // if there is a project item with that value in the drop down list
    if (projectItem != null)
    {
        ddl_projects.ClearSelection();
        projectItem.Selected = true;
    }
}
else
{
    // do something, e.g. display friendly error message or whatever else is required
}
```

Comment: ddl_projects.Items.FindByValue(projectID.ToString()).Selected = true;

Comment: yes this line throw Exception  ddl_projects.Items.FindByValue(projectID.ToString()).Selected = true; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It appears that there is no item in your drop down list with the value highlighted by projectID. This is either because you are binding the incorrect value or not the project ID value to your drop down list correctly or simply that project ID isn't in the drop down list. Try stepping through and checking the drop down list items values etc.